# HERE Fleet Telematics. Examples. Bug for vehicle Trailer Truck?

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

in the examples(https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/fleet_telematics_api) on any route I set the parameter vehicle = "Trailer truck", in the response I get: "Couldn't reach way point 1 (start links -52308626 52308626 dest links -73483065 73483065 ), closest link to destination reached: 52308626 at 50.11278/8.67522, issues: illegal access, weight".

The appearance of this error is influenced by the value of the  parameters "Limited Weight [t]" and "Weight Per Axle [t]". Maximum values at which the request is executed "Limited Weight" = 18t and "Weight Per Axle" = 10t. But the real parameters of trucks with a trailer are higher.

please tell me is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

The error message simply means the route calculation failed due to truck weight violation around 50.11278,8.67522, which is in the urban Frankfurt area and heavy weight trucks are banned.

Comment: ubiquitous such a problem - I took a point on the outskirts of Frankfurt and put a point on the outskirts of Warsaw

Comment: If needed, please provide the exact start and destination coordinates, and also the truck profile including the length, height, weight etc., and we can have a check on the routing.

Comment: https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?
waypoint0=48.794996,9.026756&
waypoint1=49.424799,8.544370&
mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&
departure=2020-08-01T11:20:31&
alternatives=10&
weightPerAxle=14t&
limitedWeight=40t&
height=4m&
width=2.55m&
length=16.5m&
trailersCount=1&

Comment: a truck of 40 tons could not drive anywhere in Germany

Comment: there is a solution?